# How to Port Free RTOS to Atmega128 on atmel studio 7?

Tags: embedded, freertos

I want to port freertos to Atmega128 on atmel studio 7, any help please

Comment: Your question is probably too large to be answered here. I would suggest to start from an existing Atmega 128 FreeRTOS demo, such as [this one](https://github.com/BlaCkinkGJ/Atmega128-SimpleProject-FreeRTOS), which is an Atmel Studio project you should be able to import.

Comment: A question better answered by Google.   If you make an attempt and have a specific issue - then is teh time to ask SO.  Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMM9u_1G5Qo is a demonstration of creating a FreeRTOS project for Mega32 - your 128 is probably no different in this respect.

Comment: Using a RTOS on a legacy 8 bit MCU isn't a very good idea. You might want to consider why you use an 8 bitter in the first please, if you actually need the kind of complexity that motivates the use of RTOS.